# Multiple threads and Sqlite - database disk image is malformed

Tags: linux, multithreading, sqlite

When I try to read (select) from sqlite database from ~1000 processes i keep getting errors like

```
SQL error: database disk image is malformed
```

or less often

```
SQL error: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

from some of threads.

I test this program & db on 3 hosts:

1. with older 1-core CPU - no problems, no errors
2. with 1-core VPS - errors occur
3. with 8-core i7 - errors occur

DB is always in /tmp/ folder so it's basically held in RAM.
Integrity check says DB is fine.

What can cause this problem and is there a solution?

Comment: "DB is always in /tmp/ folder so it's held in RAM." Don't do that.

Comment: It's there because it's relatively small and read very often. (and it's just a working copy! - i didn't mention it). Is there any particular reason I shouldn't put a working copy in tmp?

Comment: Because you are duplicating the function of the [page cache] (https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics) and you've collected data that indicates /tmp and sqlite don't like each other.

Comment: See also: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Problem was due to connection to database was opened before fork(). Many processes used one connection. Now it's opened after fork() and everything is ok.

Sqlite3 provides support to multiple selects at the same time only in the case of multiple connections to this db. In this case multiple processes were trying to query db through the same connection. On slower hosts it wasn't a problem but on newer machines probably process run too quickly and previous queries were overwritten/interrupted by new ones. Just guessing :)